# Powershell loop job in Background

Tags: powershell, loops, background

I want to start robocopy through a Powershell script invoked by task-scheduler copying files from one server to a list of hosts. It might be that one of the hosts is not available, so I want the copy jobs to start seperatly in the Background like I can do in bash with &.
Is this possible in one Powershell script?

This is what I have:

```
$i = 1
While ($i -le 9) {
robocopy \\Name_of_Server\share\ \\192.168.17.$i\share\ *.json  /MIR /r:3 /w:10
$i++
}
```

I tried with invoke-expression, Start-Job, Start-Process,... but no success... Either it does not recognize the loop or missing whatever arguments...
I´m thankful for any hint before letting a linux box do the job... ;-)

Thanks in advance

Lotte

Comment: have you tried adding an "is it responding?" test before you start the RC line?

Comment: `start-process powershell.exe -argumentlist "robocopy \\Name_of_Server\share\ \\192.168.17.$i\share\ *.json  /MIR /r:3 /w:10" -windowstyle hidden` Does this work?

Comment: `start-process powershell.exe -argumentlist "robocopy \\Name_of_Server\share\ \\192.168.17.$i\share\ *.json  /MIR /r:3 /w:10" -windowstyle hidden `Works like charm! Thanks a lot!